# How to select a single value from two different tables and divide them

Tags: sql

I have two tables that have no relationship.  I want to select a value from each of them and divide one from the other.  I'm essentially looking for something like this (although I know this is not correct):

SELECT (
SELECT MAX(row) FROM TableA /
SELECT max(row) from TableB))

How can I do this in a single SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT (cast((SELECT MAX(row) FROM TableA) as decimal) / cast((SELECT max(row) from Table2) as decimal))
```

Comment: @user2468402 Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Sql Server, not sure about other implementations of SQL.

`select (tableA.Value/tableB.Value) from (select MAX(row) Value FROM TableA) tableA, (select MAX(row) Value FROM TableB) tableB`

Answer (score 0):

The example query you provided is close; you just need to add some inner parenthesis:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(row) FROM TableA) / (SELECT max(row) from TableB)
```